# How stable is Juju 2.0 and can it be used for production of security-critical application?

Tags: juju

I am currently deploying 20 instances of a security-critical application. I'm working with Juju 1.25.6 but I'm thinking of switching to Juju 2 because it seems to solve some of the issues that are encountered in Juju 1... Is it feasible and a smart thing to do? My question more specifically:

**Can Juju 2.0 be used in production of a security critical application, and if yes under which conditions and limitations?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I wouldn't do this just yet. There are still API and upgrade breaking changes going on.

When 2.0 hits RC1, then we will add the guarantee that you'll be able to upgrade environments. Until that time, upgrade isn't guaranteed to work as we are changing API calls and database schemas.

Comment: Do you think 1.25 is suitable for deploying a security-critical app? Anyways, can some security / technical papers be found around about Juju? I'm really interested in their security decisions... Thanks kindly for your reply.

Comment: Yes I think it is fine, but if you can wait for 2.0 that would be better. Upgrading from 1.25 to 2.0 will be problematic and we don't have that planned for the short term.